# Applescript that looks for specific text in a list of text items

Tags: applescript, itunes

I have many esoteric CDs whose track names are not always in CDDB. So I'm trying to write a an Applescript that will take a list of song titles that I copy from AllMusic and paste them as track names in iTunes. When copying a list of track names from AllMusic, the format is ALMOST always:

track #
Title
Composer
Track length
A link to Spotify or Amazon

This repeats for as many tracks as the album contains. I wrote the following Applescript which works when the above format does not change:

```
set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set txt to the clipboard
set p to count paragraphs of (the clipboard)
set i to 2
tell application "iTunes"
    activate
if selection is not {} then -- there ARE tracks selected...
    set mySelection to selection
    repeat with aTrack in mySelection
        if i is less than p then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASCII character 13 -- (a carriage return)
            set newTxt to text items of txt -- not text of, text items of
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid -- restore text delimiters
            set name of aTrack to item i of newTxt
            set i to i + 5
        end if
    end repeat
end if
end tell
```

The problem is that sometimes there is one or two more or less categories (e.g. missing composer) which throws my script off. Ideally, there would be a way to have the script go through the list of text items, find track #1, paste in the very next text item, find track 2, paste in the very next text item, etc. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Here is the altered code based on my comment below:

…I tried adding "set k to 1" at the top, changing "set i to i + 5" to "set i to i + 4", and adding:
                if i is equal to k then
                set i to i + 1
                set k to k + 1
                end if
at the end of the repeat loop. Then the script would jump by 4 paragraphs. If counter 'k' didn't match the paragraph it was looking at (e.g. if k was "2" and paragraph i was not "2", it must mean that it was a group of 5 paragraphs, so "i" would advance by one. Not good scripting, but it would probably work in most cases. The trouble was that I could never get "if i is equal to k" to return as true, even when it was. Here is the code in full:

```
set tid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set txt to the clipboard
set p to count paragraphs of (the clipboard)
set k to 1
set i to 2
tell application "iTunes"
    activate
    if selection is not {} then -- there ARE tracks selected...
     set mySelection to selection
    repeat with aTrack in mySelection
        if i is less than p then
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ASCII character 13 -- (a carriage return)
            set newTxt to text items of txt -- not text of, text items of
            set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tid -- restore text delimiters
            set name of aTrack to item i of newTxt
            set i to i + 4
            if i is equal to k then
            set i to i + 1
            set k to k + 1
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end if
end tell
```

Comment: So, it appears that there is one paragraph per data value?  One paragraph is title, another is artist, another is composer, etc.  Is that correct?  It is difficult to ascertain based on your current code.

Comment: Hi Craig. Yes, that's correct.

Comment: The issue here is the location of something reliable in the list of paragraphs, to base the script on, since you cannot reasonably rely on the number of paragraphs in the current state.  Is there even a blank paragraph in there somewhere?

Comment: No, all the paragraphs run together without a gap. The one thing that is consistent is the track number is always followed by tab character. Not sure if that could be a test of some sort. As I mentioned, each track almost always consists of 5 paragraphs. When it doesn't it is almost always 4 paragraphs. That is, I can assume that 99.9% of the time that a track will have either 4 OR 5 paragraphs, though a single CD could consist of both types of tracks. If I could get the script to even just work for those scenarios it would be good enough. To that end (see note appended to original post)

Comment: If every track number is followed by a tab character, you should be able to use delimiters to first divide the text by tabs, then divide again by returns, and you should have nothing but the track names left, which is what you want.

Comment: I am not sure to get it right : your format looks : track# <tab> title <return> composer <return> track_length <return> link <return> track#, .....  am I correct ?

Comment: Testing out the tab and return delimiters, looks like format is: track# <tab> title <return> composer <return> artist <return> track_length <tab> link <tab>. Composer and link are usually present but not always. @CraigSmith Dividing by tabs combines title/composer/artist/track_length so I'm not able to then get the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for confirmation about the format. The main issue is that it is not an easy format ! So, the script must look what are the next tab or return sequence to determine what is what.

I made the script bellow which does what you need. I included many comments to make it clear (I hope !). The first rows explain what could be the 4 possible text formats that the script must handle for composer and link ( yes/no for each).

I have tested the script with the 4 formats all in sequence in the same text. You must add your iTunes routine, which can use the defined variables : TTrack, TComposer (could be empty), TArtist, TLength and TLink (could be empty).

I insert a comment where your iTunes routine must be added.

The script loops until all txt from clipboard has been used.

```
(* format of input text is made of :
track# <tab> title <return> composer <return> artist <return> track_length <tab> link <tab>
 - title, artist and track_length are mandatory
 - composer and link are optional

Therefore, there are 4 possible formats :
track# <tab> title <return> composer <return> artist <return> track_length <tab> link <tab> (= complete)
track# <tab> title <return> artist <return> track_length <tab> link <tab> ( = no composer)
track# <tab> title <return> composer <return> artist <return> track_length <tab> ( = no link)
track# <tab> title <return> artist <return> track_length <tab> ( = no link, no composer)
*)

set Ctab to ASCII character 9
set Creturn to ASCII character 13
set txt to the clipboard
repeat while length of txt > 1
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to Creturn
set Track_Title to text item 1 of txt -- the first item always contains Track# tab Title
set L to (length of Track_Title) + 1 -- L will be the ofset for next track
set T2 to text item 2 of txt -- the second item could be composer or artist
set T3 to text item 3 of txt -- the third item could be artist or (track_length tab link tab track# tab title)
if (offset of Ctab in T3) = 0 then -- the third item is artist
    set TComposer to T2
    set TArtist to T3
    set L to L + (length of TComposer) + 1 + (length of TArtist) + 1
    set NextT to text item 4 of txt -- NextT = (track_length tab link tab track# tab title) or (track_length tab track# tab title)
else -- the third item is (track_length tab link tab track# tab title) or (track_length tab track# tab title)
    set TComposer to ""
    set TArtist to T2
    set L to L + (length of TArtist) + 1
    set NextT to text item 3 of txt
end if
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to Ctab
set TTrack to text item 1 of Track_Title
set TTitle to text item 2 of Track_Title
set TLength to text item 1 of NextT
set L to L + (length of TLength) + 1
if (count of text items of NextT) is 4 then -- format is (track_length tab link tab track# tab title)
    set TLink to text item 2 of NextT
    set L to L + (length of TLink) + 1
else -- format is (track_length tab track# tab title)
    set TLink to ""
end if

-- replace this dialog by your iTunes procedure !!!!!!
display dialog "track=" & TTrack & return & "title=" & TTitle & return & "composer=" & TComposer & return & "Artist=" & TArtist & return & "length=" & TLength & return & "Link=" & TLink & return & "L=" & L

if length of txt > (L + 1) then
    set txt to text (L + 1) thru -1 of txt -- remove all current track from text
else
    set txt to ""
end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This works great and I very much appreciate the explanations as you go through. I learned a great deal!!!